# How to style a div content after fixed div header with dynamic height

Tags: css, html, position, fixed

following situation:

```
<body>
 <div style="position:fixed; width:100%">[place holder for header]</div>
 <div style="position:relative;width:100%;margin-top:100px">[content]</div>
</body>
```

I need the header always visible and at the top, so this one should be with position:fixed.
A problem occurs after self adjustments of the header - height. If the header is higher than 100px a part of the content is hidden.

How can I (CSS) dynamically set the start position of the content div regarding the end of the header.

Comment: Take care of the syntax : 'width' and not 'widht'

Comment: Do you need a pure CSS solution, or can you use JavaScript too? I'm afraid there's no pure CSS solution for this.

Comment: I prefer css but if there is no solution I''ll be happy of the javascript answer.

Comment: I just spent some time looking into this, and I'm pretty sure it's impossible without JS.

Comment: As long as you remove any onload scripts, html ids and all similar dynamic stuff in the 2nd block, ingenious answer from @Etienne is a css-only solution for this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm still looking for a CSS only solution, but for the moment here's an idea using just one line of JavaScript – when using jQuery:

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content').css('marginTop', $('#header').outerHeight(true) );
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="header" style="[…]">[place holder for header]</div>
    <div id="content" style="[…]">[content]</div>
</body>
```

The advantage of using `.outerHeight(true)` is, that it takes care of borders and margins you may have applied to your header.

Comment: this actually works fine too. I don't think there is a CSS-only solution

Answer (score 6):

CSS only solution (although not super clean) could be to display the same block twice: 1st block "position: fixed", 2nd block "visibility: hidden". Since both would have the same height, the role for the 2nd block would be to push down the page content to the appropriate level.

Comment: It works perfectly! This could be the only CSS-only solution.