# Using setIntervel() to offset content on page with fixed header with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval

My problem is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286141/how-to-style-a-div-content-after-fixed-div-header-with-dynamic-height) except the thing that fixed element may change his height dynamically during application lifecycle (other data, viewport change, etc... ).

I'm using `setInterval()` function with 100ms interval to update offset of content element depending on header height.

```js
jQuery(function($){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('article').css('padding-top', $('header').outerHeight());
    }, 100)
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3sr2mg44/) for it (*change the width of the resulted page to see how it works*).

For user experience it looks just great, but I'm curious **is there a better way?**

**What are the disadvantages of this approach?**

Answer (score 1):

The major disadvantage is that you consume CPU every 100ms. And it doesn't do anything most of the time.

There is a better way. Just emit an event after the fixed element changes height and bind your css adjusment to it. Something like:

```
$(document).trigger('my_element_changed_height');
```

wherever the height changes and

```
$(document).on('my_element_changed_height', function() {
    $('article').css('padding-top', $('header').outerHeight());
});
```

Comment: This approach makes me mix logic of application with application view. I have to watch on this trigger event during all application maintenance (if some business rule will change in the future). I'm too lazy for it. And what about width changing?

Comment: If you think that you mix logic with view then it seems that you already have them incorrectly mixed. That's how you would correctly write your application: normally you would wrap any width/height change into a function and only use that function. Therefore adding such functionality is easy to maintain. The layer between jQuery and your logic. That's how good design works. What you are doing is a nasty hack which may backfire on you if you have lots of such background timers and other CPU intense stuff going on.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use jquery.ba-resize.js library. Here is a link: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin
It allows you to use resize event on any DOM element. But if I'm not mistaken this library uses setTimeout functionality and I'm not sure that's better in performance.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** time goes and web evolve, [**position: sticky**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning)

```css
header{
    position: sticky;
}
```

**Old Answer:**

Here is another solution that comes to my head. I was thinking how would be great have such `position : fixed-relative` :) *(That fixed on viewport but doesn't desapear from normal flow)* And here is [an idea](https://jsfiddle.net/054qamb9/) how to emulate this behaviour. Set header element position as relative.

```css
header{
    position: relative;
}
```

And add some listner to scroll event.

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('header').css('top',$(this).scrollTop() );
    });
});
```

It's much pretty than have infinity loop with setInterval or trigger some event across your application.

Unfortunately **it will not work on most [touch devices](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/08/19/onscroll-event-issues-on-mobile-browsers/)**